# Using Entity Framework causes an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a class library which is used to implement the logic of my project but when I try to run my code this error is shown :

> Could not load file or assembly EntityFramework ...

I think this error is meaningless because the EF6 has been installed on my Visual Studio 2013.

Inside the `app.config` I have defined a connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con0"
         connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=jasmin;server=(local)"
         providerName="System.Data.sqlclient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my context class:

```
public class SchoolClassContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolClassContext() : base("name=con0") { }
    public DbSet<SchoolClass> SchoolClassCtx;
    public DbSet<Teacher> TeacherCtx;
    public DbSet<List<Student>> StudentsCtx;
}
```

This is my method:

```
public virtual TransActionInfo AddClass()
{
    transActionInfo = new TransActionInfo();        
    classContext = new SchoolClassContext();          

    var schoolclass = new SchoolClass() {
                ClassID = base.ClassID,
                Title = base.Title,
                Location = base.Location,
                Schedule = base.Schedule,
                State = base.State,
                TTeacher = base.TTeacher,
                Students = base.Students                
         };

    try
    {
        classContext.SchoolClassCtx.Add(schoolclass);
        classContext.SaveChanges();

        transActionInfo.Status = TransactionStatus.Status.Successful;
        transActionInfo.ObjectName = base.GetType().Name;
        transActionInfo.ObjectLastState = schoolclass;
        transActionInfo.TransactionTime = DateTime.Now;

        return transActionInfo;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        transActionInfo.Status = TransactionStatus.Status.Abort;
        transActionInfo.Msg = e.ToString();
        transActionInfo.TransactionTime = DateTime.Now;

        return transActionInfo;
    }           
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

After installing EntityFramework with NuGet-Packagemanager, you should make sure that you have EntityFramework in your references list:

[image: VS References]

After building your solution you should have a EntityFramework.dll in your debug folder side by side with your own executable:

[image: VS Debug Folder]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to install EF in your project with nuget package manager console.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework